# Printing form a script/application which is running as Windows service

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, ms-word, windows-services

I have a bit of a (at least for me) odd problem. I have created a (Java) Application which (when some conditions are meet) runs a PowerShell script that uses MS-Word to print some document. I run this application through a simple batch file (java call).

It works like a charm when I run the application through my batch, **BUT** when I (using NSSM or AlwaysUp) turn it into a windows service the and trigger the printing process it fails. I see in the task manager that a MS-Word process is started, and it take away lots of CPU, but it does nothing (no matter how long I wait).

Simplified code:

```
$objOffice = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$objDoc = $objOffice.Workbooks.Open("C:\printTest\printFile.xlsx")
$objDoc.printout()
$objDoc.Close($false)
$objOffice.quit()
```

I have tested this on other computers as well... Same result.

Also interesting:
EDIT: This part written where was my fault, and fixed it.

At this point I am not even sure that it has something to do with the powershell command, but I am getting out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe it is related to the user account executing the script ?

Comment: Could you add you code in here? And if it is too long could you create a [mcve] to post in here? As is right now, we can only shoot in the dark as well..

Comment: @Berger : Tried it also with the admin account. Same problem remains.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 code added

Comment: @BenH For testing purposes, I have set the service to start manually... Meaning that it only runs after the user is logged on.

Comment: @BenH When I got on the service settings I only have 4 tabs: General, log on, recovery, dependencies... I dont see that option anywhere. But does that secutiry option really matter, if through manually starting the process I allready ensire that option?

Comment: Are you running the service in a user account where you have installed Excel and can log in and run it normally?

Comment: @CoreTech Yes I am .

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\printTest\printFile.xlsx' -Verb print
```

Also, take a look at [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/), which says

> *You might notice the option for “Allow service to interact with desktop”, which we mentioned earlier – by default, services are not
>   allowed to access your desktop unless this box is checked, and this
>   checkbox is really only there for legacy support.*
>
> *But just checking
>   that box doesn’t immediately give them access – you would also need to
>   make sure that the NoInteractiveServices value in the registry is set
>   to 0, because when it is set to 1, that checkbox is ignored and
>   services can’t interact with the desktop at all. Note: in Windows 8,
>   the value is set to 1, and interactive services are prohibited.*

Comment: I have also tried this command... As for allowing the service to interact with the desktop... It works off the whole script but nothing happens.